# Reverse the 4 last characters from each line of a text file in Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to move the last 4 characters from each end of a line of a text file at the front of the line.

For instance I have the following line:
6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10050

and I want the last 4 digits to get in the front of the line so I have the following code to do that:

```
import sys
import re
import os

def rearrange(word):
 if word.endswith('0'):         
     word = word[-4] + word[-3] + word[-2] + word[-1] + word[:-4]    
 print(word)
 return word

rearrange('6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10050')
```

I get the following output, hence so far so good, it works:

00506c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b1

> > > 

However, when I try to do it for a small file with an iteration loop.
Say the text file to read from is with the following lines:

```
6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10050
8d6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10020
9a6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10030
```

I want to work the same way but it I cannot get it to work.
There is something obvious that is happening that I cannot see it, can someone spot it and help me out here please?

```
import sys
import re
import os

def rearrange(word):
     if word.endswith('0'):         
         word = word[-4] + word[-3] + word[-2] + word[-1] + word[:-4]    
     print("print while the routine is executed:")
     print(word)
     return word     

file_write = open (r"reversed-test_text1.txt",'wt')

with open(r"test_text1.txt") as file_read:
    for line in file_read:        
        r = rearrange(str(line))
        file_write.write(r)
     
file_read.close()
file_write.close()

f = open("reversed-test_text1.txt", 'r')
print('Print the 4-char reversed text:')   
print(f.read())
```

When I execute it I get the following which is not what I wanted:

```
Print the 4-char reversed text:
6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10050
8d6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10020
9a6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b10030
```

Does anyone have any idea why? It must be dead simple but I fail to see it (not that experienced in Python either).

Comment: You don't need to close a file if using a context manager (`with` part)

Comment: Did you inspect the value of `line` in the `for line in file_read` loop? What is the last character of that string? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, that by reading the lines from the file, you have a `\n` in the end of each line.
By your check for the zero in the `rearrange`-method, you are simply skipping your rearranging.

Comment: yes, he is also not reading each line but each character, he should do `for line in file_read.readlines()`

Comment: @Axeltherabbit no, that's not it. I checked that out locally because I also didn't know this way of iterating through it, but it works just fine.

Comment: oh, right, I always used readlines or split, didn't aspect it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The `if word.endswith('0'):` condition is not satisfied, because each line ends with a newline character (`'\n'`).

To make it work as you expect, you might rewrite the loop as follows:

```
with open(r"test_text1.txt") as file_read:
    for line in file_read:        
        r = rearrange(line.rstrip())
        file_write.write(r + os.linesep)
```

The `.rstrip()` method trims the whitespaces characters from the end of the string.

The `os.linesep` is the default line separator of the current platform.

Comment: Absolutely right, it has now worked. I get the 4 last digits now at the beginning of the line. Many thanks